# Nexus 7 2013 WiFi (flo) bootloader unlock fails

Tags: fastboot, nexus-7, bootloader-lock, nexus

Update: I don't know what I did differently apart from factory resetting it a lot of times, but it finally went through and unlocked.

---

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader on my Nexus 7 2013 WiFi 32GB (flo). I turned it off, pressed power button + volume down, which soon greeted me with "the bootloader". I then ran `fastboot oem unlock` which prompted the tablet to ask me whether I really want to unlock the bootloader, and I subsequently navigated to yes using the volume keys and confirmed with the power button. Following that, this was printed to my computer's terminal:

```
(bootloader) Unlocking bootloader...
(bootloader) erasing userdata...
(bootloader) erasing userdata done
FAILED ()
Finished. Total time: 17.372s
```

As you can see, it only says `FAILED ()`. No error code. Looking at photos of others unlocking the bootloader, it seems that the next step should be erasing cache, however it evidently does not progress there. I can still boot into Android though. First boot initially greeted me with an "erasing" screen which had an Android on it, and all user data was erased (as expected). I did try repeating the procedure once more after letting it boot Android again but the result was the same.

Other things I have tried are manually formating the userdata and cache partitions via the recovery menu and factory-resetting from within Android, however neither of these were fruitful.

I have tried 2 different computers and 2 different USB cables but they yielded the same results. How might I go about resolving this so that I can unlock the bootloader?

Comment: Have you enabled the "OEM unlock" slider in the developer settings? Without that option enabled bootloader unlocking will not work. If unlocking is still not possible try to perform a factory reset from within the running Android system (via settings menu).

Comment: @Robert I was thinking that too, but neither looking through the developer settings nor searching reveal any such option. I think it may be due to that this device initially shipped with Android Jellybean. I'll try a factory reset from within Android though. I was also thinking re-flashing might help.

Comment: I realise that even re-flashing an image from Google requires unlocking the bootloader. Reset from within Android was not fruitful either.

Comment: Which Android version is installed? According to some blogs there should be an "Allow OEM unlocking" option in developer menu. You can also try the command `fastboot oem unlock-go`.

Comment: @Robert Latest one available for the Nexus 7 2013 WiFi, i.e. 6.0.1 with security patch level being 5 August 2016. Are these blog posts about the Nexus 7? And I'll try that.

Comment: Result was unfortunately the same as `fastboot oem unlock`.

Comment: what happens for fastboot `erase` or `format:ext4` userdata/cache? also there is a `fastboot flashing unlock` for all devices and `unlock_critical` for some

Comment: Update: I'm not sure what I did differently, but now it went through and unlocked.